# CSS Background Positioning

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have an image ontop of another image. For instance, a lot of sites have a main background, I would assume used in the html tag and another background, like a simple color used for the body tag. But they make it 75% of the screen and have it centered so part of the html background is showing. I am stuck on how to center and make the body tag 75% of the screen. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use `margin:0px auto;` and `position:absolute` on the `div` that you want to be centered.

first one `0px` tells it that top and bottom portions do not have any margin. second property tells it that make right-left margin auto. so that the div is centered.

to make this working the div needs to have a `width` and be absolute positioned.

demo (bonus header):
http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/GPpeD/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper div and give it a 75% width and apply whatever background you would like then set it's position to center it will gives you the desired output.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.wrapper{
width:75%;
height: 100%;
background-color:red;
background-position:center;
margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="background-color:black;">
<div class="wrapper">this is a 75% width wrapper</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `auto` just tells the browser to split up the available space evenly between the left and right side of the element

Answer (score 0):

```
background: 
   url(backgroundOne.png) 60px 10px no-repeat,  /* On top,    like z-index: 4; */
   url(backgroundTwo.png) 10px 10px no-repeat,   /*            like z-index: 3; */
   url(backGroundThree.png);                      /* On bottom, like z-index: 1; */
```

Try above code in CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can try assigning css background image property to the body and create a new div then assign another background onto it. And set the width of the container to 75%. Or else if you are planning to use img tag then you can give z-index property to it. For positioning the div container to center give margin: auto;